# Save several array in one file using np.savetxt()

Tags: python, file, numpy

I want to save several arrays in one file, I have a method named `writeOnTxtFile` and I'm calling that in a loop.

But when I run my code, there is only one array in my txt file

This is my `writeOnTxtFile` method:

```
def writeOnTxtFile(path):
    image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
    arr = np.array(image)
    arr = np.ravel(arr)
    np.savetxt('dataset.txt', arr, fmt='%d', newline=' ', delimiter=',')
```

and i'm calling that here:

```
while line:
       writeOnTxtFile(line)
       line = listName.readline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.savetxt('dataset.txt', arr, fmt='%d', newline=' ', delimiter=',')
```

will just overwrite the array over and over until the last array is saved in the .txt file.
Instead open the file before with append and in binary mode.

```
f = open("dataset.txt", "ab")
```

and then use:

```
np.savetxt(f, arr, fmt='%d', newline=' ', delimiter=',')
```

this should append all arrays to your file. You might want to write \n after every np.savetxt() for better readability with:

```
f.write("\n")
```

so all together your code should look like this:

```
def writeOnTxtFile(path):
    image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
    arr = np.array(image)
    arr = np.ravel(arr)
    with open("dataset.txt", "ab") as f:
        np.savetxt(f, arr, fmt='%d', newline=' ', delimiter=',')
        f.write("\n")
```